# Two login forms share saved browser data, how to disable?

Tags: xhtml

I am developing a website which makes use of two login forms, one for regular users and one for administrators. Since administrators can also have an independent regular account, I would like to clear the form from any autosaved data from the browser. This way the admin panel won't have incorrect credentials that may have been filled out in the other form in an earlier stage.

Is this possible, if so, how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged this question XHTML. I don't think there is any standards-compliant way to do that in XHTML. Maybe some JavaScript trickery, but it would be messy.

HTML5, however, defines the "autocomplete" option for forms, so you could write your `<form>` tag like this: `<form action="..." autocomplete="off">` and HTML5-compliant browsers will not autofill the fields (remember to set the HTML5 doctype!) Doing this results in the user seeing something like this: [image: no autofill]

**Edit** based on OP's comment: changing the name of the fields would (in theory) prevent one field's values from autocompleting another's. If the fields in your user login form are `username` and `password` and you called the fields in your admin login `admin_username` and `admin_password`, the values of one would not be suggested for the other.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a solution to the false credentials, however, the administrators would need to fill in the form each time. Is there any documentation as to what defines that a form should be autocompleted?
Would giving the form and fields a completely different name help with this?

Comment: Hmm doesn't work, different names on fields will not prevent cross auto completion